# Existence of a real number $c$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a probability space and $f\colon X\to\Bbb R$ be measurable and not constant almost everywhere. I need to show that there exists a real number $c$ such that if $A$ is the set of $x\in X$ so that $f(x)\geqslant c$, then $0<m(A)<1$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_c:=\{x,f(x)\geqslant c\}$. We have $\lim_{c\to +\infty}\mu(A_c)=0$, because the $A_c$ are nested and $\mu$ is finite. We also have $\lim_{c\to -\infty}\mu(A_c)=1$. If $\mu(A_c)\in \{0,1\}$ for all $c$, define $c_0:=\inf\{c,\mu(A_c)=0\}$ to get that $f$ is constant almost everywhere.

Comment: You are welcome.